# Уважаемые эксперты, помогите, пожалуйста: нужно ли ставить запятую в данном случае. Лично мне так и хочется поставить для усиления смысла

Tags: пунктуация

В результате укрепления и улучшения качества жизни наиболее развитых государств под названием «Север»(,) происходит ухудшение общественного развития стран так называемого «Юга», что, в свою очередь, влечёт обнищание и моральную деградацию вторых, народ которых видит свой выход зачастую лишь только в примыкание к террористическим организациям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая тут допустима как авторский знак. Рекомендовать я её не могу.

> В РЕЗУЛЬТАТЕ (чего), предлог
>
> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом 'в результате', обычно не
>   обособляются.
>
> В результате этого процесса явилась просьба пани Попельской к мужу
>   выписать из города пианино. В. Короленко, Слепой музыкант. В
>   результате этой недостойной суеты мы получили приказ возвращаться. М.
>   Анчаров, Сода-солнце.

http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=791

Answer (score 0):

Запятая возможна. И даже рекомендуется, поскольку это распространенное обстоятельство причины.

Comment: Кем рекомендуется?